# Regex expression for 6 alphanumeric with - between every second char beginning with AY

Tags: regex

I cant seem to generate a regex expression that validates a string only if it has AY at the start, is only 6 alphanumeric char long with every second char seperated by a -, examples are as follows

valid

```
AY-B2-AX
AY-12-8A
```

ect. It must begin with AY.

invalid

```
YA-B2-AX
A1-12-8A
```

etc

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^AY(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}){2}$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/9

Answer (score 0):

```
^AY-[A-Z0-9]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{2}$
```

[live example](https://regex101.com/r/sT9aC2/3)

Comment: This regex does not check if a string starts with `AY`. However, if used with specific functions in certain languages, it can.

Comment: @stribizhev did you have a look at the live example?

Comment: [Certainly](https://regex101.com/r/sT9aC2/2). Just add words before... As I said, without a regex flavor indicated, this might fail to work for OP.